# O que define uma pergunta como bem recebida?

Tags: debate, medalhas, edições-sugeridas

Nas medalhas Curioso, Inquisitivo e Socrático existe uma descrição de como recebe-las que é:

> "Fazer uma pergunta bem recebida em X dias diferentes e manter um
>   registro de pergunta positivo".

Já fiz algumas perguntas aqui no site que tiveram alguns "up's" mas só tenho 1 ponto na barra, então fiquei na dúvida aqui, o que define a pergunta como "bem recebida" ou "mal recebida"?

Não seria melhor que o texto dessas medalhas fossem revisados com a definição desse status?

Comment: O q vc chama de "um ponto na barra"

Comment: O texto da medalha deve ser sucinto e não explicar todo critério. Algumas nem tem o critério revelado. De qualquer forma a medalha existe para incentivar o bom comportamento, os critérios não são importantes, basta a pessoa saber que ela deve tentar fazer boas perguntas sempre.