# Ambiguidade na descrição de medalha

Tags: debate, medalhas

A descrição da medalha [Inquisitivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/103/inquisitive) é a seguinte:

> Fazer uma pergunta bem recebida em 30 dias diferentes e manter um registro de pergunta positivo

No meu modo de ver há uma ambiguidade:

- Fazer uma pergunta por dia (o que daria um total de 30 perguntas em 30 dias) e todas elas serem bem recebidas;
- Ou fazer um única pergunta bem avaliada em 30 dias

O mesmo vale para as medalhas [Curioso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/102/curious) e [Socrático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/104/socratic).

Comment: [O que define uma pergunta como bem recebida?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6003/5878)

Comment: Lá, ele não menciona a duplicidade no significado, mas sim questiona o que seria uma `pergunta bem recebida`

Comment: Pelo que interpreto e sei é "Fazer uma pergunta por dia (o que daria um total de 30 perguntas em 30 dias) e todas elas serem bem recebidas", mas de facto dá para interpretar de outra forma. Ou seja poderia tar escrito de forma a não permitir multiplas interpretações.

Comment: Aproveitando... 30 dias consecutivos ou não? Acho que isso também poderia ficar mais claro

Comment: Me parece que não precisa ser 30 dias consecutivos

Comment: @Costamilam Eu tenho a medalha Curioso no meta e minhas 5 perguntas não foram em dias consecutivos. De qualquer forma, a descrição diz "X dias diferentes", para mim isso já diz que não precisa ser consecutivos... O principal problema parece ser o critério exato (a ambiguidade mencionada na pergunta), talvez se a gente adicionasse uma entrada no [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/112052), similar a [essa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/401803), isso já eliminaria essas dúvidas...

Comment: Lendo o FAG do SO em inglês me sugere a segunda opção: `fazer um única pergunta bem avaliada em 30 dias`